# Tomcat session sharing not working when the browser makes the call to another server

Tags: java, session, tomcat

I have 2 tomcats `(server1 and server2)` running each one with separate war `(war1 and war2)`. I added this `<Context sessionCookiePath="/">` to the `context.xml` on both the servers.

```
server1 : http://localhost:9090/myapp1 - spring application 
server2 : http://localhost:8080/myapp2 - grails application (version 2.3.4)
Tomcat version 7.0.47
```

In my case server1 is the entry point. These are the steps.

1. User hits the url of server1 via browser.
2. Logs in with his credential
3. Now the server created a new session after successful authentication.
4. Clicks on a button which is linked to server2

I expect the same session is used by the server2.

After I started both the servers I was expecting when **(server1) war1's UI** makes the call to **server2** would get the existing session from browser. But when the call (while debugging) reaches server2 there is no session and server2 creating a new session.
At the same time if I hit the server2 url directly in the browser address bar server2 is picking up the session from the browser which is created by server1, which is correct.

My question is why it is not happening when (server1) UI makes call to the server2 ??!! 
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: The ports are different and thus the cookie even with path / is for a different host/port combination.

Comment: @Joshua Moore Then why it is able to pick the session when I hit the url directly in the browser?

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood the sequence. The cookie/request is from the browser and tied to the browser. So, unless the browser is making the request to both servers then it's going to be a different session. App1 to App2 is a different session than Browser to App1. I'm assuming that you are using HTTP requests between App1 and App2 since you don't indicate if you are are aren't.

Comment: Thanks @JoshuaMoore I updated my question with the actual steps. Browser makes call to App1 and after getting into some jsp page user clicks on a button which makes the call to App2. So it should be of the same session correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why the session wasnt visible to the other server. When calling from the UI the call was made my ajax (same origin). Ajax doesnt send session cookie as part of the request, which made the other server to generate a new session.

Though the wars are deployed in different server all the url should point to the same domain. for e.g., domain as `http://localhost:9000` and it should be differentiated using the app name `http://localhost:9000/app1, http://localhost:9000/app2`. To achieve this I configured Apache (version 2.4) server. Then it started working with out any problem

There could be some other way too. Just wanted to share the answer that I found.